# Expander scrolling problems

Tags: wpf, scroll, material-design, expander

I have a an `Expander` inside a `Stackpanel`, inside a `ScrollViewer`.
Now when I move my mouse over the expanded expander, the scrolling of the scrollviewer doesnt work anymore.
Can someone help me understand why?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller">
    <StackPanel  Name="Panel1">
            <Expander Header="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Strings.GeneralSettings}}" IsExpanded="True">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ProjectName,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Projektname" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ProjectLead,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Projektleitung" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.City,Mode=TwoWay}"  material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Ort" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ZipCode,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Postleitzahl" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.Street,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Strasse" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.HouseNumber,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Hausnummer" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ContactName,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Ansprechpartner vor Ort" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ContactEmail,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Kontaktemail" Margin="10" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10" SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectDataService.CurrentProject.ProjectStatus,Mode=TwoWay}" material:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Projektstand">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Abgenommen" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Eingebaut" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I found out, that it is the MaterialDesign Framework, which breaks the scrolling. To enable the framework I need to put

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

into the application.ressources.

the second line breaks the scrolling

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I get `ScrollViewer`, put `StackPanel` inside it, then put `Expander` inside it, and then finally put large content inside `Expander` - scrolling works fine after expanding and mouse moving.

Comment: After removing all bindings and `material:TextFieldAssist.Hint` entries from provided example (to be able to compile it), scrolling still working. Can you provide complete program example with code-behind (but minimal as possible) where scrolling also will not be working?

Comment: After adding my Code until it stops working I found out, that the problem seems to be the materialdesign framework I am using. When I put it in my code, the scrolling does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It is a bug in the material design nuget: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1395

it is fixed in the current preview for materialdesignthemes 3.0. Check "include prerelease" in nuget manager to be able to select the preview versions for this nuget package.